# How can I horizontally move the nodes from SankeyNetwork, using NetworkD3 in R?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

```
links2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/tul45082/Desktop/CMA/DNA/links.csv")
nodes2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/tul45082/Desktop/CMA/DNA/nodes.csv")

sankeyNetwork(Links = links2, Nodes = nodes2, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "names", 
              colourScale = my_color, LinkGroup = "group", 
              NodeGroup="group",fontSize = 10,fontFamily = "Arial", 
              nodeWidth = 3,
              nodePadding = 10, sinksRight = FALSE)
```

This is the code I have written.

I have managed to plot the Sankey diagram and I can manually move the nodes in the Y-axis. My problem is that I can not move the nodes in the X-axis.
Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?